# What's with the "getting rejected from the Field of Reeds" dialogue in episode 1?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, moon-knight-2022

In the first episode of *Moon Knight*, titled "The Goldfish Problem", there was this dialogue between Steven Grant and a little girl in the museum:

> **Steven Grant**: They'd take this big metal hook, right? And they go up the old nozzle and... [*makes slurping sound*] all the organs would come out. Except for the heart.
> **Little Girl**: How come?
> **Steven Grant**: Because they believed you needed your heart to be judged in the Underworld and only the worthiest would be allowed to pass through the Field of Reeds.
> **Little Girl**: And did it suck for you? Getting rejected from the Field of Reeds?
> **Steven Grant**: Well, that doesn't make sense 'cause I'm not dead, am I?

The girl's question is strange. They are talking about an ancient Egyptian afterlife belief, but the girl asked why Steven Grant got rejected from the Fields of Reeds which (as Steven Grant replies) doesn't make sense because he's not dead.

The girl's question also foreshadows events that will happen in the later episodes. Steven Grant (and Marc Spector) do indeed die and get to the ancient Egyptian afterlife/underworld (the Duat) in ep. 4. Steven gets stuck in the sands of the Duat and was unable to enter ("rejected from") the Field of Reeds (ep. 5). Only Marc was able to pass through the Field of Reeds (ep. 5) but decides to leave it (ep. 6) and rescues Steven from the sands.

In ep. 5, in the Duat, Taweret (Egyptian goddess of women and children, and Duat guide) says to Steven and Marc:

> Because the Duat's true nature is impossible for the human mind to comprehend, you may perceive this realm as something more easily recognizable to you.

I was wondering if perhaps the ep. 1 scene where the "rejected from the Field of Reeds" dialogue took place might be part of the Duat and Steven was perceiving it as "something more easily recognizable to [him]."

Also, Marc / Steven is insane (as Marc himself admits in ep. 5). After Khonshu releases Marc and Steven, they get back to Dr. Harrow's office, where they realize that Dr. Harrow and his office are just figments of their imagination.

It seems that the little girl knows more than she lets on. Is she a figment of Marc / Steven's imagination (like the scenes with "Dr. Harrow")? Or was she of a supernatural background, maybe connected to one of the Egyptian gods? (Egyptian gods have been shown to be able to speak through humans in *Moon Knight*.) Or is this something more mundane, just a kid being a kid and asking strange questions?

Comment: She might instead be referring to how Marc became Moon Knight, where he was near death, and saved by Konshu. Although that’s not literally being rejected from the Field of Reeds, that might be where he would have ended up if not for Konshu’s intervention.

Answer (score 12):

I think you may be reading too much into it. It's just as likely that the girl is simply casually insulting him, saying that he's an unworthy person who would be rejected. Steven responds to her somewhat nonsensical insult with confusion and dismissal.

And yes, it does serve as a clever hint to later events, but I think that it's more coincidental than prescient.

Comment: "_the girl is simply casually insulting him_" - after seeing the episode I am sure she was implying Steven looked like death from the lack of sleep. Steven doesn't catch on fast enough and misses the insult. Either that or she's implying he came back from The Field of Reeds sans brain

Answer (score 12):

She's not insulting Steven. She's using 'you' in reference to whomever it might be that was rejected.

Steven turns her question into a joke.

What she is really asking is if it sucked if a soul was rejected from the Field of Reeds. Here it is a little more clearly:

> Steven Grant: Because they believed [they] needed [their] heart to be judged
> in the Underworld and only the worthiest would be allowed to pass
> through the Field of Reeds.
>
> Little Girl: And did it suck for [them]? Getting rejected from the
> Field of Reeds?

Grant makes a little clever answer to her question, and as it turns out a bit of foreshadowing.

Comment: I'm not so sure she is using "you" that way. If she was, wouldn't she say "would it suck for you" instead? Just like how Steven says "they'd (they would) take this big metal hook..."

Comment: @CaveJohnson - Grant actually says 'Because they believed *you* needed *your* heart to be judged in the Underworld and only the worthiest would be allowed to pass through the Field of Reeds.' I just changed it for clarity. She is speaking in the past tense with the use of the words *did* and *rejected*.

Comment: That little girl was absolutely insulting Steven. Her tone and body language made that even more abundantly clear than her actual words.

Comment: the four downvotes give me great fear for the state of English language literacy

Answer (score 7):

A proper Moon Knight comic fan would be better suited to explain (or deny) this but: what I understand is that the Moon Knight canon is intentionally (and canonically) muddled.  What is real? What are his delusions? Where are the lines between them? These are all questions that must always be asked, but you'll never really have answers to them. The girl could just be a hallucination reflecting his own lacking sense of worth. Maybe the entire series starts after his death and rejection from the field of reeds, being tested to see if he can balance his heart or otherwise just come to grips with the truths about himself and reality; or just plain being tormented, but not in a fire and brimstone brutality way, but in a subtle but constant inability to achieve satisfaction and closure. Maybe it's just confusion caused by the ambiguity of the English language, as argued in other answers: was she using a generic "you", and did Steven humorously or mistakenly interpret it as a personal "you"? Being a young girl, perhaps she just doesn't speak as precisely and unambiguously as we, as adults, may desire. Did Steven just hallucinate her saying what we, the audience heard, when she really said something else entirely?

With a mind as broken as Steven's/Marc's, there are no certain answers to what is and isn't a figment of a fevered and warped imagination.

Comment: +1 This is my favorite answer; it's intentionally ambiguous for the purpose of being unsettling. Another possibility on the menu is that it's a god with advance knowledge speaking momentarily through the girl, which is another thing that happens at numerous point in the series.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins but we don't see her take on the normal 'possessed' actions that happens when a god inhabits an avatar

Comment: @NKCampbell: But it's very early in the series of events, so perhaps the effect is more subtle at that time.

Comment: that's a stretch. Don't look for zebras in a field of horses

Answer (score 0):

She didn't mean "you" as in Steven. She was referring to this hypothetical person who was rejected from the Field of Reeds. Steven was being cheeky in his response because of the way she used "you" in her question.

Comment: @DavidW That is just how the English language works, what more support is needed? You can see that 'you' and 'your' were used in the previous line in the same manner.

Comment: @BradyGilg Well referencing the relevant preceding lines that use it in the same fashion would probably be a good addition to reinforce your interpretation.

Comment: @DavidW - see my answer for the support ;)

Comment: @NKCampbell So you're saying this answer is redundant? ;)